# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null(index):110 onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a problem with my alert box. I want to design a cross for closing the box by clicking on it:

```
 <div id="alert">
 <img src="cross.png" onclick="document.getElementById(alert).style.display = 'none'" width="15px" height="15px" style="float: right; margin-top: 3px; cursor:pointer;"/>
 <p style="margin-top: 20px;">alert text</p>
 </div>
```

When I click at the cross an error appears. I pasted it in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put 'alert' in quotes. It's a string

Answer (score 1):

You should put single quotes around 'alert' inside getElementById -- that method takes a String.

So:

```
<img src="cross.png" onclick="document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none'" width="15px" height="15px" style="float: right; margin-top: 3px; cursor:pointer;"/>
```

You use single quotes, because you've already wrapped it with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div id="alert">
 <img src="cross.png" onclick="document.getElementById('alert').style.display = 'none'" width="15px" height="15px" style="float: right; margin-top: 3px; cursor:pointer;"/>
 <p style="margin-top: 20px;">alert text</p>
 </div>
```